# How to run video from raw folder using vitamio?

Tags: android, android-videoview, vitamio

I'm trying to play mp4 video from raw folder. It is working fine in native video player but when I tried to play it using vitamio then it did not work for me. Are there any way to run mp4 video from raw folder in android using vitamio library??

I used this code to run video from raw folder.

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Comment: why you so specific about vitamio player  ?

Comment: Because I now using vitamio player. Any good library out there instead of native one?

Comment: checkout this one http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/

Comment: What type of getting error? plase post your video view code beacuse i have good knowladge about vitamio library...thanks

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya I just added this code. Please help me.

Comment: which used of videoView ,Vitamio library or default android videoView?

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya absolutely vitamio. I am not using default android videoview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitamio does not support to play video from raw folder. They are working with it and hope in next release they will fix the bug. We can solve this problem just copying the video from raw to sd card.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath("your path");
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(
                    LibraryVideo.this));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

            mVideoView
                    .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            Log.e("StartVideo", "OnPrepare");
                            mVideoView.start();
                        }
                    });
```

video_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Sharifur Rahman please try this code and give replay this is working or not.?

Answer (score 1):

I had use this vitamio library for no. of projects, but till today, i can asure tell you that vitamio is not supported raw data, you have to converted the data to some valid format to play the video. supported format are  : rtsp,rtmp,http,ftp,https, , hope you will understand.